# facebook android sdk doesn't show account picker

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-authentication

I'm trying to implement facebook sdk 4 (`com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)`)   for authentication in my app. I'm using `LoginButton` to login into the app. The problem arises after the first login.

The account picker is displayed only the first time. And then onwards when I click the login button, it automatically logs in with the account I chose the first time.

This is the code I'm using to logout:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
    ....
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
});

protected void logoutFacebook() {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how to show an account picker each time a user clicks the login button ?

Comment: Have you tried this and see what happens ? https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10206555982332742

Comment: Thanks @LeandroOcampo, will try that and let you know. But I think this is a device issue and shouldn't require an api call.